# Searching In MongoDB using mongoose(Node.js)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

My MongoDb has a collection with `deviceName` and `registrationID` fields.

The `deviceName` field stores the email and `registrationID` stores unique IDs, I want to search and get the `registrationID` using the email entered by the user.

How can I do this in Node.js Mongoose?

Comment: You did not show any code, or any research effort. I am not 100% sure on what you are trying to do. But I would start by reading up on Mongoose queries. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html There are some examples there.

Answer (score 0):

```
- First of all, create index which field, you want to search.
  Here, In this case deviceName is field in which email are stored.

db.collectionName.createIndex({deviceName:"text"});

-And, For Serach:
db.collectionName.find({$test:{$search:"janvi@gmail.com"}})
```